# Modify GraphQL Schema-Parser

Tags: parsing, graphql, graphql-js

I want to modify the graphql syntax and parse process for my own needs.
E.g. that the client can send queries with path-based arguments:

```
type Foo {
  name: String
  anotherField: String
  bar: Bar
}

type Bar {
  name: String
  anotherField: String
}

type Query {
  foos(arg: String): [Foo]
}

#relevant part: bar.name
query {
  foo(arg: bar.name) {
    name
    anotherField
  }
}
```

Advantage: e.g. filter on nested objects without setting them in the query. I know that changes in the resolvers are necessary, but first the parser (and lexer!?) has to accept the "new" syntax. At the moment the concept is causing a

```
GraphQLError: Unexpected character ".".
```

Any ideas?

I know that some libraries like Prisma or Hasura have implemented good filter alternatives but i need my custom solution.

Comment: This question is too broad for SO. The source code for the reference implementation is open source. If you want to modify the parser to support some additional syntax, fork the repo and hack away. However, it's most likely not worth the effort. By implementing changes like this server-side, you would make your service incompatible with most existing clients and development tools. That's the whole point of having a spec.

Comment: FWIW, there's an RFC [here](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/issues/248) that's I think along the lines of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i will take a look.